# How to revert Ubuntu back to stock

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to get a fresh ubuntu desktop without re-installing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18920/any-way-to-get-a-fresh-ubuntu-desktop-without-re-installing)

Is there any command or methods to **remove all the packages and applications that I installed** in Ubuntu desktop/server and revet it back to the stock setup.

Comment: A similar question was asked here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/39658/how-to-uninstall-all-but-the-default-ubuntu-packages
Very briefly put, you'll need to obtain a list with the default packages. Comparing this to the list of your packages will show which packages need to be uninstalled. If you then find a way to automatically uninstall the package list you've generated (this is not explained in the referred answer) you're good to go.

Alternatively, you might save yourself some time by simply reinstalling as @blueXrider suggested