# How can I do a fresh reinstall of ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, reinstall

I have a computer that is 100% ubuntu not a dual boot. most turials I find are for dual boot comps. I tried creating a live usb from unetbootin but it does't seem to work. Is there a program or something i can run for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reinstall Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5655/how-do-i-reinstall-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu Default installer does give this option. Choose the option to reinstall Ubuntu. Unetbootin makes it's own option for the boot option. The default can be used if you make a Live USB with a program like StartUp Disk Creator that is available in Ubuntu.

[image: Live USB program]

[image: Installer options]

Option to reinstall appears when Ubuntu us already installer. If you want to be able to reinstall Ubuntu without losing your files you will need to separate the Ubuntu system in an exclusive partition and the files on HOME which is where all user data is stored in another partition.